# adding Panels to a GridSizer through a for loop WXpython

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, wxpython

I've been stuck on this issue and I feel like is a silly one. I have 3 list . list1 contains all the panels to be added to my gridsizers. list2 contains a list of my gridsizers which are 3x3. im trying to add these panels from list one to the sizers and once it reaches 9 then place in the next gridsizer. Below is my code and the error I keep receiving

```
listOfWaferPanels = []
listOfGridSizers = []
listOfPanels = []
for lotID, wafNum in df3.groupby(['LOT_WF']):
        df4 = wafNum[['X_COORD', 'Y_COORD', 'HB_NUM']]
        print(wafNum)
        print("\n")
        my_list = df4.transform(tuple, axis=1).tolist()
        self.temp_panels = wm_core.WaferMapPanel(self, my_list, waferDesign, data_type='discrete'.lower())
        listOfWaferPanels.append(self.temp_panels)
        waferNum += 1
numOfTabs = (waferNum//9) + 1
    for tab in range(numOfTabs):
        tabString = ("Page"+ str(tabNumber))
        tempGridSizers = wx.GridSizer(3,3,0,0)
        tempPanel = wx.Panel(self.waferTab,wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        tabNumber += 1
        listOfGridSizers.append(tempGridSizers)
        listOfPanels.append(tempPanel)
for tab in range(numOfTabs):
        for i in range(waferNum):
            listOfGridSizers[i//9].Add(listOfWaferPanels[i], 1 , wx.EXPAND)
        listOfPanels[tab].SetSizer(listOfGridSizers[tab])
        self.waferTab.AddPage(listOfPanels[tab], "tab", select=False)
```

and the error Is below

```
listOfGridSizers[i//9].Add(listOfWaferPanels[i], 1 , wx.EXPAND)wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "!sizer || m_containingSizer != sizer" failed at ..\..\src\common\wincmn.cpp(2470) in wxWindowBase::SetContainingSizer(): Adding a window to the same sizer twice?
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry this was very silly. If anyone runs across the same issue here is what I did wrong.
I added my panels to the gridsizers and they went in fine, but the issue came when the outer looped again because this meant that I was going to add the panels to the gridsizer again ! which actually explains the error code. I simply split up the nested for loops into 2 separate ones and it worked